# Trying to find and install libstdc++.so.5 to run C++ with mex for MATLAB

Tags: linux, matlab, dependencies, shared-libraries, mex

I am using the **BGL** libraries for **MATLAB** found [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10922) on **fileexchange**. I get this error when using a function from this library under **Ubuntu 10.04 LTS** (this error did not occur under Windows, where it worked normally).

```
??? Invalid MEX-file
'/home/alex/Documents/MATLAB/MATLABsvnWorkingDir/Bloom/graphAnalysis/analysisAttempt2/functi    onsDownloaded/matlab_bgl-4.0.1/matlab_bgl/private/components_mex.mexglx':
libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
directory.
Error in ==> components at 42
[ci sizes] = components_mex(A);
Error in ==> modularize_graphs_Alex_hugeMats_BlondelCode at 16
[comnts,~] = components(graph);
```

The whole problem appears to be with `libstdc++.so.5`. I cannot find it in the synatpic package manager. There is this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1243005) which discusses the problem but I have tried those steps without any progress.

I tried the solution listed [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/matlab-bgl/+question/70191):

```
alex@alex-laptop:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install libstdc++.so.5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package libstdc++.so.5
alex@alex-laptop:~/Desktop$
```

I have also tried other solutions that I found on the web but nothing fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

`sudo apt-get install libstdc++5`

This should install the package, including the libs needed.

Comment: I get an error `alex@alex-laptop:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install libstdc++5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package libstdc++5` what could be blocking it?

Comment: You need the backports repos available.