# Error: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found

Tags: matlab, compilation, conv-neural-network

I am trying to compile matconvnet-1.0-beta20 with Matlab 2016a on Ubuntu 16.04. Initial phase of compilation works fine:

```
 untar('http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/download/matconvnet-1.0-beta20.tar.gz') ;
 cd matconvnet-1.0-beta20
 run matlab/vl_compilenn
```

The error happens when I run `vl_simplenn(network, image)` which gives following error:

```
Invalid MEX-file '/home/matconvnet-1.0-beta20/matlab/mex/vl_nnconv.mexa64':
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version
`GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/matconvnet-1.0-beta20/matlab/mex/vl_nnconv.mexa64)
```

To understand the cause of problem, I run `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC` which doesn't give any output `bash: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: Permission denied`
Also `more /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` gives no output:

```
******** /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: Not a text file ********
```

I did some research and found some possible solutions:

1. http://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/162466

> The problem is that MATLAB secretly changes LD_LIBRARY_PATH on startup
>   to point to the MATLAB version of GLIBC++, so that GLIBC++ 3.4.9 can
>   no longer be found. **The solution is to modify matlab/bin/.matlab7rc.sh
>   so that "LDPATH_PREFIX" contains the path to the version of GLIB
>   installed with your compiler**, then this is found before the
>   matlab-supplied library.

so I edited `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/.matlab7rc.sh` and modified `LDPATH_PREFIX=''` in 195th line to `LDPATH_PREFIX='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'`.

After applying this change, the problem still exist.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20288112/5510001), I copied .matlab7rc.sh to current working directory of project, but still error persist.

2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/719028/version-glibcxx-3-4-21-not-found

According to first answer, running this command 
    `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6`

gives an error:

`ln: failed to create symbolic link 'usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6': No such file or directory`

Seems like second solution suggests changes of `LD_PRELOAD` path in `.matlab7rc.sh`, but it is not anywhere inside the file.

3. [How to tell mex to link with the libstdc++.so.6 in /usr/lib instead of the one in the MATLAB directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959306/how-to-tell-mex-to-link-with-the-libstdc-so-6-in-usr-lib-instead-of-the-one-i)

From Matlab directory in `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin$` I run 
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`

but the problem still exist.

---

Maybe there I didn't apply the solution in the correct way Or maybe there is another solution elsewhere that I didn't find. Please let me know, I am very confused!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929332/version-glibcxx-3-4-11-not-found-required-by-buildw-mexglx?rq=1 -> Seems like it is solved by deleting  libstdc++.so.6

Comment: I have had good results with just deleting the libstdc++ file that comes with MATLAB, as long as you have a newer version of GCC installed on your system.

Comment: ...of course renaming or moving it instead of deleting it is a lot safer, so you can put it back if things go sour. :)

Answer (score 6):

You need before execute (matlab in my case) add path of library:

In console execute this:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 matlab
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. 
In my case, to solve it, I first ran "locate" to list all the possible versions of the library in the system.

> locate libstdc++

As an example, I report the result on my system

[image]

I then set the most recent version of "lib" by exporting the environment variable:

> export LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21"

So, the fullpath of the library to be set depends on where it is allocated in your system.

Answer (score 0):

if someone is still interested, it is enough to remove the version of libstdc++.so delivered with MATLAB. For instance:

```
$ sudo mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.old
$ sudo mv libstdc++.so.6.0.28 libstdc++.so.6.0.28.old
```

and restart MATLAB. This will force MATLAB to load the (usually newer) version oflibstdc++.so installed on your system.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`
2. Install this package:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test 
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```
3. MAYBE the second solution you mentioned really works, but you have done it before. So you cannot operate in the same way again because you have ever linked `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` to `usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6`. TRY rebooting?

Also, you use MATLAB R2016a, but this command applies to R2014a. Was it that you ignore this point?